# How does canvas rendering through javascript is working iternally?

Tags: dom, html5-canvas, internal

Can anyone explain how browser is rendering the canvas objects and allowing to draw objects using javascript.

Comment: That is ... a broad subject ... So, to answer the question, *Probably* (there is probably someone that can explain it). Can they do that in less than the maximum number of characters allowed in SO answer, probably not. Please narrow your question to a specific problem.

Comment: I just want to explore how DOM rendering and painting is different from canvas painting using js

Comment: That's still an overly broad subject. We can't give full explanation of how such a broad topic works, moreover when we have no clue of what you already know. Also, "rendering" has many meanings in this context.

Comment: ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(Xpos,YPos,width,height);
ctx.fillStyle = color; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

how these lines are getting executed and getting painted on canvas tag declared in html